# Numbers that are not roots of equations involving linear combinations with integer coefficients of compositions of monomials and certain functions

Tags: field-theory, transcendental-numbers

Real numbers that are not solutions of polynomial equations with integer coefficients are called transcendental numbers.

Now consider the set of functions $S = \left\{\sin(x), 1, x, x^2, x^3, ... , x^n, ...\right\}$. Let $\bar{S}$ be the closure of $S$ under function composition and linear combinations with integer coefficients. For example $x^7 + 27x^5 + 3(\sin(x^3))^3 + \sin(\sin(x + \sin(2x))) + 1 \in \bar{S}$.

What numbers are the roots of such equations? For example $\pi$ is a root of $\sin(x) = 0$ so it is no longer transcendental. Is the set of roots countable like in the case of algebraic numbers? What if we add other functions to S, for example we add all elementary functions to S? What if we also allow multiplication of functions, in order to make S a field?

Comment: Since I think such an equation has a countable number of roots, I think that the set of such roots is still countable. But I am not sure.

Comment: I don't know if they have a name, but with that many functions in $\overline{S}$ the question of whether its elements have a zero or not [is recursively undecidable](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2003-131-07/S0002-9939-02-06753-9/S0002-9939-02-06753-9.pdf). For simpler sets of function [there are algorithms](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5437218/#CR23). The study of zero sets of similar sets of functions is studied by model theorists.

Comment: Keywords: [exponential field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_field), [Tarski exponential function problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_exponential_function_problem), [Schanuel conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schanuel%27s_conjecture).